Trigger alert message when browesr tab shows unread messages
I have a WP site where I need to add code snippet to trigger an alert message,
Similar to - alert ("You have a new message"); however I need it to only trigger when the tab in question title changes from the page name to show a new message or messages - for example: Tab title goes from 'inbox' and changes to '(1) New Message' or (2) New Message and so on, this is when it triggers an alert message.
I can get it to show alert message on load and after a set time just only.
To add I am running ten tablets in kiosk mode with notifications disabled but webview alert messages work.
Browser Tab picture

how does the count change ? with javascript or when the page reload ?

@mmm Hi The count changes, so if its showing one message and a new message is received it will then show (2) and so on. ideally ever time the count changes the alert message shows.

@mmm i believe it changes via java script, the reason  I am not sure is that i use a plugin in call bettermessages and there  a tick option that gives the option to display count in the tab.

you have to find how it changes to hook your code to this change.
